# sifr menu list problems, height of object calculated wrong

Tags: list, drupal, menu, sifr, height

I am using Drupal and have sifr set on list items, and also a, a:hover are set via Drupal so that the links hover. I looked at the sifr3-rules.js file drupal's render module creates and it looks good. and in fact my other sifr items look fine... But the list item ones are goofing for some reason... There is extra space below the list,
so if i have a list item, and inside of that, I have a unordered list with more list items, the Flash Object made in the 1st li (which will cover the rest of the sublist items too), is too bid so you see space under the children until the next parent li comes up. (so looks like extra bottom padding on that portion of the list in IE8... in FF almost similar but each subitem has space at bottom... with javascript turned off, you see the list items look fine by themselves)....

Also if the parent list item is shorter than the sub list items text, the width for the flash object is set only as long as the first list item, and therefore cuts off the rest the sublist item's text.

Any idea how to resolve any of these?
Only unusual thing i see i am doing is setting forceSingleLine and preventWrap (which dont make a difference if taken off).

****Edit, I may just try to figure out how to get Drupal's menu-block module to output a  around my hyperlinks in the list items... then i can target the div's with my rule (and the a,a:hover rules will apply), so each menu item gets its own sifr object instead of sifr3 trying to figure out how to do the lists and sublists.

Very useful to me is anyone knows a way to target a hyperlink (<a> tag) and also allow a:hover rules. I know how to do it with pretend another tag that includes hyperlinks, like if i had <h2><a>sometitle</a></h2>, i could have a rule for h2, but then use the a, a:hover rules in the sifr3-rules.js file to target that. so i would need a way to target the hyperlink in the list, but also apply a :hover to it (not sure if this can be done since its not underneith for example the h2 tag).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just overrode theme_menu_item
to return ''. $link ."". $menu ."\n"; (so added a div class). and used a sifr rule to target '.mymenu .menu_item'. then a sifr flash object is created for each list item hyperlink but won't try to wrap the whole list (and its sublists) like before. Seemed to fix both problems :)